# AWS ARM EC2 Not able to access apache after installation

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, amazon-ec2

So, I pull up my favorite instructions to install [LAMP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04).

AWS only has instructions for their AMI which uses yum which I am not using.

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Secure              ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Secure (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I have run this command

```
 sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

And yes, I have configured my firewall rules

```
Port range Protocol Source       Security groups
80         TCP      0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-3
80         TCP      ::/0        launch-wizard-3
22         TCP      0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-3
22         TCP      ::/0        launch-wizard-3
443        TCP     0.0.0.0/0    launch-wizard-3
```

What is the magic command to get to the web server from the external IP?
Thanks!

Oh to answer the question did I check the status of apache. Yes I did.

```
sudo systemctl status apache2
 ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor   preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-05-04 20:31:22 UTC; 2h 49min ago
   Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
 Process: 2117 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Main PID: 1530 (apache2)
  Tasks: 55 (limit: 2326)
 Memory: 6.6M
 CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
         ├─1530 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
         ├─2121 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
         └─2122 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you confirmed that Apache is running on the EC2 instance?

Comment: yes, I looked and it is still running.

Comment: I have done nothing in the last two hours and came back and put the IP address in the browser and the site showed up. Go figure! There must be a delay in the coming together of all the AWS services. So, my suggestion and new operating practice is to launch the server and wait 24 hours to start the build.